# iOS didFailToConnectPeripheral: with error Code=0 "Unknown error."

Tags: c++, ios, error-handling, core-bluetooth, objective-c++

I got this error when develop delegate class for iOS mainly c++ program. I use iOS CoreBluetooth framework and get didFailToConnectPeripheral: with error

```
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=0 "Unknown error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error.
```

After couple of hours I check threads, executions - almost everything. My answer below

Answer (score 0):

the problem in ,y case inside method that connects our custom device to iPhone:

```
- (void)tryToconnectToPeripheral{
    if (_peripheral && _peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateDisconnected) {

        [_centralManager connectPeripheral:_peripheral
                                   options:@{CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey: @(YES)}];
    }
}
```

**Problem detail** if you fire ***[centralManager connectPeripheral:options:]*** before connection to peripheral did complete - you'll get the error with code=0.

Solution is just changing IF condition to

```
if (_peripheral && _peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateDisconnected)
```